# Create New Column Based on Previous Row and Multiple Conditions in R

Tags: r, row, conditional-statements, plyr

I have the following sample data frame:

```
x
date          product   release    
2012-01-01    A         0                   
2012-01-02    A         0                   
2012-01-03    A         0                   
2012-01-04    A         1 
2012-01-05    A         0     
2012-01-06    A         0   
2012-01-07    A         0   
2012-01-08    A         0   
2012-01-09    A         0   
2012-01-10    A         0   
2012-01-11    A         0   
2012-01-12    A         0 
2012-01-01    Z         0                   
2012-01-02    Z         1                   
2012-01-03    Z         0                   
2012-01-04    Z         0   
2012-01-05    Z         0     
2012-01-06    Z         0   
2012-01-07    Z         0
```

I want to iterate through each row and generate a dayssince column based on
how many days it's been since the release.

Few things to keep in mind:
 -  new product released = 1     no product released = 0
 - the output needs to be unique to the date **and** the product

The desired output would be:

```
   x
    date      product   release    dayssince  
    2012-01-01    A         0          0         
    2012-01-02    A         0          0        
    2012-01-03    A         0          0        
    2012-01-04    A         1          1
    2012-01-05    A         0          2
    2012-01-06    A         0          3
    2012-01-07    A         0          4
    2012-01-08    A         0          5
    2012-01-09    A         0          6
    2012-01-10    A         0          7
    2012-01-11    A         0          8
    2012-01-12    A         0          9
    2012-01-01    Z         0          0        
    2012-01-02    Z         1          1        
    2012-01-03    Z         0          2        
    2012-01-04    Z         0          3
    2012-01-05    Z         0          4
    2012-01-06    Z         0          5
    2012-01-07    Z         0          6
```

I've tried everything I could think of from ifelse statements and for loops to ddply.

The simplest way I've been able to approach the problem is to do the following conceptually:

```
x$dayssince <- ifelse(x$release > 0, 1, 0)
```

- Then check each row in dayssince.
 - If dayssince == 1, then 1
 - If dayssince < 1, then check row above.
 - If row above is > 0 , then use value of row above + 1
 - All this unique to the product.

Thank you in advance!

## **UPDATE/CLARIFICATION:**

For the same products that release multiple times per year, I'm looking to get the number of days *since the last release*.

For example:

```
    x
    date      product   release    dayssince  
    2012-01-01    A         0          0         
    2012-01-02    A         0          0        
    2012-01-03    A         0          0        
    2012-01-04    A         1          1
    2012-01-05    A         0          2
    2012-01-06    A         0          3
    2012-01-07    A         0          4
    2012-01-08    A         0          5
    2012-01-09    A         0          6
    2012-01-10    A         1          1
    2012-01-11    A         0          2
    2012-01-12    A         0          3
    2012-01-13    A         0          4
    2012-01-14    A         0          5
```

etc...
Thanks for the flag @DMC

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `ave` from `base R`

```
 x$dayssince <-  with(x, ave(release, cumsum(release), product, 
                          FUN=function(y) cumsum(cumsum(y))))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,dayssince:=cumsum(cumsum(release)) ,
                   .(product,cumsum(release))][]
 #  1: 2012-01-01       A       0         0
 #  2: 2012-01-02       A       0         0
 #  3: 2012-01-03       A       0         0
 #  4: 2012-01-04       A       1         1
 #  5: 2012-01-05       A       0         2
 #  6: 2012-01-06       A       0         3
 #  7: 2012-01-07       A       0         4
 #  8: 2012-01-08       A       0         5
 #  9: 2012-01-09       A       0         6
 # 10: 2012-01-10       A       1         1
 # 11: 2012-01-11       A       0         2
 # 12: 2012-01-12       A       0         3
 # 13: 2012-01-01       Z       0         0
 # 14: 2012-01-02       Z       1         1
 # 15: 2012-01-03       Z       0         2
 # 16: 2012-01-04       Z       0         3
 # 17: 2012-01-05       Z       0         4
 # 18: 2012-01-06       Z       0         5
 # 19: 2012-01-07       Z       0         6
```

Comment: This works for the example provided in the OP. But what happens if there are multiple releases per product?

Comment: @DMC I didn't check with those multiple releases per product.  Thanks for the comment

Comment: @DMC thanks for the q.  In my df the same products can be released multiple times, but only on different days. For example Product A can be released on 2012-01-04  and again on 2012-05-01.  I just need to be able to list how many days it's been since their latest release.  So if we're looking at the date 2012-05-02, I would like 2, not 120 (which is based off of the first release date).

Comment: @lelgohary Could you update your post with an example that mimic the dataset and the expected output.

Comment: @lelgohary I think the solution still works based on the new condition.  For example `x$release[7] <-1` and then try the code above

Answer (score 1):

The solution uses `dplyr` and creates an intermediate variable `release_num`:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  mutate(release_num = cumsum(release)) %>%
  group_by(product, release_num) %>%
  mutate(dayssince = cumsum(cumsum(release)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One comment that I have is that you ask for a solution that *'iterates row-by-row.'* This isn't an **R** way of doing things. **R** works on vectors--typically column vectors. Therefore, any solution will require a bit of a workaround. You could switch to something like **SAS** which does explicitly work row-wise.

My solution uses the `plyr` library, although it's not vectorized. It may therefore be slower than some alternatives.

```
# given vector of release dates and output vector, produce "dayssince"
ds <- function(rel.dts, x) {
  n <- length(rel.dts)
  x[1:rel.dts[1]] <- 0
  for (i in 2:n) {
    x[(rel.dts[i-1]):(rel.dts[i]-1)] <- 0:(rel.dts[i]-rel.dts[i-1]-1)
  }
  x[rel.dts[n]:length(x)] <- 0:(length(x)-rel.dts[n])
  return(x)
}

# use ds() on a given product
ds.prod <- function(dat) {
  dat <- dat[order(dat$date, decreasing=FALSE),]
  rel.dts <- which(dat$release ==1)
  ds <- get("ds")
  dat$daysince <- ds(rel.dts, x=vector("integer", length= nrow(dat)))
  return(dat)
}

# split by product and run
require(plyr)
dat <- ddply(dat, .var="product", .fun= ds.prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is coming from a database, it may be easier to create a view with a computed column used to calculate the days since release.

I am currently too tired to post any SQL code, but if it is an approach you would consider, I can provide some example code tomorrow.